# jqGrid: navGrid reloadAfterSubmit does not add a new row when editurl is not valid

Tags: jqgrid

I am trying to test adding a new row and deleting a row in jqGrid and I find that the grid does not refresh to show the new row or remove the deleted row after adding/deleting a row. The server side piece is not in place yet for adding/deleting, so I just fed editurl the same url I used to load data into the grid.

```
.navGrid('#' + id + '-pager',
            {addtext: 'Add Code Value', deltext: 'Delete Code Value', edit:false,add:true,del:true,search:false, refresh:false},
            {closeAfterAdd: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true} /* Edit options */,
            {closeAfterAdd: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true} /* Add options */,
            {reloadAfterSubmit: true} /* Delete options */);
```

Am I missing something here? I thought reloadAfterSubmit should update the grid with the added/deleted row?

Thanks.

**Edited**: My custom add function, which is unnecessarily complicated is (note: this should be a client side add only)

```
addfunc = function() {
//Find dirty unsaved row if any and add to the grid before adding empty row

                var dirtyRow = jQuery('#' + id).find('tr[editable]');
                var dirtyRowId = dirtyRow.attr('id');
                if (dirtyRow.length > 0) {
                    dirtyRow.addClass('data-isDirty', true);
                    var rowData = jQuery('#' + id).jqGrid('getRowData', dirtyRowId);
                    jQuery('#' + id).jqGrid('addRowData', rowId, dirtyRowId);
              //The row when added to the grid should not be editable but a normal row

                dirtyRow.find('input').each(function() {
                        var text = jQuery(this).attr('value');
                        jQuery(this).replaceWith(text);
                    });
                }
                var rowId = Math.floor(Math.random()*1000) + 'add_new';
                jQuery('#' + id).jqGrid('addRowData', rowId, that.getEmptyRow(colModel), 'first');
                var firstRowId = jQuery('#' + id).jqGrid('getDataIDs')[0];

                            //Add an empty editable row at the top
                jQuery('#' + id).jqGrid('editRow', firstRowId);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use *dummy* URL, then it don't answer on HTTP POST requests probably. You can solve the problem by usage of `mtype: "GET"` option. In the case you can use any existing server URL from the same site like `"/"`:

```js
.navGrid('#' + id + '-pager',
    {addtext: 'Add Code Value', deltext: 'Delete Code Value',
        edit:false,add:true,del:true,search:false, refresh:false},
    {mtype: "GET", closeAfterAdd: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true} /* Edit options */,
    {mtype: "GET", closeAfterAdd: true, reloadAfterSubmit: true} /* Add options */,
    {mtype: "GET", reloadAfterSubmit: true} /* Delete options */);
```

As `editurl` parameter of jqGrid you can use any existing URL like `editurl: "/"`

Comment: Hmm...still not seeing the new row being added. What do I need to do if I want the new row to be added client side with no changes being sent to the server?

Comment: This url seems to demonstrate how to add rows locally without posting to the server but am not able to figure out what param I have to set to enable this: http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html

Comment: @Ramya: Adding new row locally is very easy: you can use `addRowData`. It seems me not what you asked in your question.

Comment: I think I am trying to do something simple but my code reflects otherwise :) So, I am trying to click on the navgrid add button and have an empty editable row show up in the grid. This row will automatically show the input boxes in edit mode when I click on the add button. There is no server side post that needs to happen. The initial data load for the grid is from the server in json format. I edited the original post to add my custom addfunc which I use to add the editable row. When the user clicks on add again, the row data gets added to the grid client side and a new editable row shoes up

Comment: I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this? Thanks @Oleg for helping out...